# Cannot create process: proc_open: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, php, mediawiki, lua

I've seen this question posted around with no solution. And I've seen other posts that are related ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232427/proc-open-fails-with-permission-denied) [two](https://superuser.com/questions/455935/php-script-cant-run-bash-script-sh-permission-denied)) but don't help.

Permissions are set, executable, ownership is set, no SELinux, PHP can execute shell commands, PHP not in safe_mode, php-pcntl is installed.

I'm using Arch Linux, PHP 7.1, MediaWiki 1.28, php-fpm, nginx 1.10.3, and scribunto downloaded from MW for 1.28.

I'm trying to use Scribunto for Template:Navbox. The error is when I go to the template page, the luastandalone in scribunto raises the error trying to start a logger.

The error I'm getting:

```
Lua error: Cannot create process: proc_open(/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/extensions/Scribunto/errorFile): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The LocalSettings.php lines:

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/Scribunto/Scribunto.php";
$wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = 'luastandalone';
$wgScribuntoEngineConf['luastandalone']['errorFile'] = "$IP/extensions/Scribunto/errorFile";
```

And the permissions:

```
$ ls -l extensions/Scribunto/

total 96

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19917 Nov 18 19:15 COPYING

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   609 Nov 18 19:15 Gruntfile.js

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2793 Nov 18 19:15 Scribunto.magic.php

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  8111 Nov 18 19:15 Scribunto.namespaces.php

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9437 Nov 18 19:15 Scribunto.php

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 18 19:15 common

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   702 Nov 18 19:15 composer.json

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3945 Nov 18 19:15 composer.lock

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  4096 Jan  9  2016 engines

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 Feb 26 23:44 errorFile

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   278 Nov 18 19:15 gitinfo.json

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 18 19:15 i18n

drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Nov 18 19:15 modules

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   276 Nov 18 19:15 package.json

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   505 Nov 18 19:15 phpcs.xml

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Jan  9  2016 tests

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Nov 18 19:15 vendor

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    48 Nov 18 19:15 version
```

Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: The relevant permission is that of the Scribunto directory.

Comment: @Tgr That solved the problem. I don't know why though.

Comment: I take it the `/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/extensions/Scribunto` directory wasn't writable to the PHP user so it could not create `/usr/share/webapps/mediawiki/extensions/Scribunto/errorFile`, which is what the error is complaining about.