# sh(conf) script can not run php file

Tags: php, shell-script, centos-7, selinux, fail2ban

I am trying to run a php script within my fail2ban action file.
When I disable selinux everything works fine, but when I enabled it again I get a constant error in my fail2ban log.

php.conf (action)

```
actionban = php /usr/share/nginx/html/worker/fail2ban.php <ip>
```

Error log:

```
 -- stdout: 'Could not open input file: /usr/share/nginx/html/fail2ban.php\n'
```

How can I run this file with Selinux enabled?
Thanks in advance guys

Comment: Why have you got a `\n` in there?

Comment: @davidpostill that has to do something with the error log system, because from my action config file there is no input for a new line or what so ever.

Comment: I found my answer @ https://superuser.com/questions/455935/php-script-cant-run-bash-script-sh-permission-denied By Tonin - Thanks